# How to calculate Diagonal difference in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a **N*N** Matrix.Now i want to know the diagonal difference of this Matrix.What will be the best approach of this solution?

I am trying with given approach:

Such as it is **3*3** Matrix say it is:

```
11 15 85
66 72 21
14 21 47
```

the diagonal simple formula will be:

```
firstD= (11+72+47) = 130
secondD = (85+72+14)= 171
diagonalDiff = |firstD - secondD| = |130-171| = 41
```

If I count every row such as first to find out `firstD` (First row's first value + Sec row's Sec value + Third row's third value+..).This is my thinking.
Can anyone tell me best approaches?

Comment: need two loop, let me do it for you.

Comment: Its done. Check out the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978131/how-to-calculate-diagonal-difference-in-php/36978271#36978271)

Comment: @FrayneKonok - you can do it in one loop, due to the fact that the number of rows and colums are equal. see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$arr = array(
    array(11, 15, 85),
    array(66, 72, 21),
    array(14, 21, 47),
);

$arrDiag = count($arr);

$firstD = 0;
$secondD = 0;

$i = 0;
for($j = 0; $j < $arrDiag; $j++){
    $firstD += $arr[$i++][$j];
    $secondD += $arr[$arrDiag - $i][$j];
}

echo abs($firstD - $secondD);//41
```

Comment: Since `$arrDiag` is from count function I believe it is necessary to apply a "-1" to the "$secondD" variable account there inside for loop. It sould be like `$secondD += $arr[$arrDiag - $i - 1][$j];`

Comment: @RicardoPHP, Look at the previous line where the $i already get incremented by 1, So the value of $i at second line inside loop will be 1 for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Model your matrix with a multi-dimensional array and iterate through it. The easiest way should be the following:

```
<?
$matrix = array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5,6),array(7,8,9)); //Insert or define your matrix here..
$n = count($matrix); //Size of matrix, thanks to VolkerK
$firstD = 0;
$lastD = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $firstD += $matrix[$i][$i];
    $lastD += $matrix[$i][$n-$i-1];
}
echo $firstD."\n";
echo $lastD;
```

Comment: `$n = 3;` that would be `count($matrix)` + the precondition: $matrix is an n*n array.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pseudo code for your problem using **one simple loop**:

```
// $array - predefined 2 dimentional array with $N rows and $N columns
$result = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<$N;$i++) {
 $result += ($array[$i,$i] - &array[$i,$N-$i-1]);
}

return echo abs($result);
```

that way you can do the calculation in **one** pass, and do a diff between two elements in each row insead of calculation the sum of each diagonal

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function diagonalDifference($arr) {

  $left = 0;
  $right = 0;
  $i = 0;
  foreach($arr as $ar){
      $left+= $ar[0+$i];
      $right+= $ar[count($ar) - (1+$i)];
      $i++;
  }

  return abs($left - $right);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    $result=0;
for($i=0;$i<=count($arr)-1;$i++){
    $result= $result+($arr[$i][$i])-($arr[(count($arr)-1-$i)] [$i]);
}
return abs($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you need:

```
$first = 0;
$second = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < N; $j++) {
        if($i == $j) {
            $first += $matrix[$i][$j];
        } else if($i + $j == N) {
            $second += $matrix[$i][$j];
        }
    }
}

$diagonalDiff = abs($first - $second);
```

Where `$matrix` is a N*N array

Answer (score 1):

Just using the function [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php):

```
function diagonalDifference($arr) {
    $i = 0; 
    $n = count($arr);
    return abs(array_reduce($arr, 
        function  ($c, $str) use (&$i, $n ) {
        $i++;
        return $c + $str[$i-1] - $str[$n-$i];
   }, 0));
}
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/l57vd7)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$first_diag=$second_diag=0;
$matrix=array(array(11,15,85),array(66,72,21),array(14,21,47));
     foreach($matrix as $index=>$sub_array){
         $first_diag +=$sub_array[$index];
         $second_diag +=$sub_array[count($matrix)-1-$index];
     }

    print  abs ($first_diag-$second_diag);
```

Answer (score 0):

For one you can use a matrix library like [Math_Matrix](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix). But if this is the only operation you are gona need then it's best to write a generalized function for this using the same method you quoted yourself.

```
function diagonalDiff($n){
  $firstD = 0;
  $secondD = 0;
  for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){
      if($i == $j) {
        $first += $matrix[$i][$j];
    } else if($i + $j == $n) {
        $secondD += $matrix[$i][$j];
    }
    }
  }

  return abs($firstD-$secondD);
}
```

Should give you the answer you need for a matrix of a given size $n. (Only square Matrixes ofcourse :) )

Answer (score 0):

Another better solution and it's easy to understand:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(11, 15, 85),
    array(66, 72, 21),
    array(14, 21, 47),
);

$arrDiag = count($arr);

$firstD = 0;
$secondD = 0;

$i = 0;
for($j = 0; $j < $arrDiag; $j++){
    $i++;
    $firstD += $arr[$j][$j];
    $secondD += $arr[$arrDiag - $i][$j];
}

echo abs($firstD - $secondD);
?>
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/650085)

Recently solved this question in [Hacker Rank](http://hackerrank.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$m=array(array(3,4,-1,11,2),
        array(-3,2,1,6,9),
        array(3,4,6,5,-2),
        array(1,9,9,7,-3),
        array(12,9,16,7,-3));
echo count($m)."<br>";  
$i=0;
$j=0;   
$ek=0;
$k=0;
$n=1;
$es=count($m)-1;
for($i=0;$i<count($m);$i++)
    {
      for($j=0;$j<count($m);$j++)
        {
          echo $m[$i][$j]."  ";
        }
       echo "<br>";
    }
echo "<br>";
for($k=0;$k<count($m);$k++)
    {
      for($n=0;$n<count($m);$n++)
        {
         if($k==$n){
             $ek=$ek+$m[$k][$n];
             }

        }
       echo "<br>";
    }
echo "<hr>";
$p=0;
for($k=0;$k<count($m);$k++)
    {
     echo $m[$k][$es-$p]."<br> ";
     $p++;
    }


?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I used different variable names, I had to take this to my vs code.

```html
$b = array(
    array(1,2,5),
    array(3,4,5),
    array(3,4,5)
);

//So for each diag
echo $b[0][0] + $b[1][1] + $b[2][2]; //to sum the first diag
echo $b[0][2] + $b[1][1] + $b[2][0]; //to sum the second diag

//notice the pattern 00, 11, 22 vs 02,11, 20. hence why I have  written the function below

function difference($b){

$d1 = 0;
$d2 = 0;
$count = count($b);

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $d1 += $b[$i][$i];
    $d2 += $b[$i][$count-1-$i];
}

return abs($d1 - $d2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the instructions was given by the site, mislead me. However, I solved it in this way,

```
    $n = count and store the length of input array
    //define variables to store first diagonals and second diagonals  
    $fd = 0;
    $sd = 0;
    //loop through the 2D array with $i increment


        $j = get an array from the main array   
        //in each iteration
        $pd += get the values from the left to the right and add;
        $sd += get the values from the right to the left and add;
    }
    
    find absolute difference between the sums using built in abs function and return it;
```

I think this would help someone