# Array Digonal difference in php

Tags: php

Can you guys help me out to solve the array program in php.
the diagonal difference program

```
a[]={11 2 -4 
     3  8  2
     12 3  -18}
```

how to we get answer please give me guidance i am newbie to php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36978271/2518525

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate Diagonal difference in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978131/how-to-calculate-diagonal-difference-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to minimal research to get answer to your question.

I searched for `diagonal difference` and it gave numerous results and that were pertaining to your question.

Diagonal difference is basically you are taking the diagonal elements of your array and summing them up and then doing it both the sides.

So for your array you need to start of with left side, so it will `11 + 8 + (-18)` and subtracting that with the diagonal from the right `-4 + 8 + 12`

Basically you need to subtract and take absolute value of it.

Based on the above comments, to implement through PHP, you may take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978131/how-to-calculate-diagonal-difference-in-php/36978271#36978271).